React js Chakra UI Accordion items are remain closed by default for mobile responsive only
Currently, I am facing issue in React js Chakra UI Accordion. Issue is all items are remain closed by default for mobile responsive only but keep open for desktop and tablet view.
I am not using any different condition for responsive but it behaves differently for mobile view only.
My goal is to all accordion items should open by default.
<Accordion defaultIndex={defaultIndices}>

If use below code with setTimeout than it is working. Without setTimeout it is not working.
const [openItems, setOpenItems] = useState<number[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (defaultIndices && defaultIndices?.length > 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setOpenItems(defaultIndices);
      }, 500);
    }
  }, [ defaultIndices]);

  return (
    <Accordion defaultIndex={defaultIndices} index={openItems}


I have fixed the issue and There was no issue related to accordion. but It was issue from its parents component which makes the accordion item height to 0.

Assuming that defaultIndices is an array, try to add allowMultiple={true}

I think you should do the map on your index of accordion items and chakra ui component will look's like
<Accordion defaultIndex={[0,1,3,4]} allowMultiple>

[0,1,3,4] - possible to do the map

I have already tried this, but it doesn't work only for mobile responsive only. whatever value I provide, by default all accordion nav items are closed for mobile. but it works for tablet and desktop view.
